# Automate EDMX Refresh

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I update objects using Entity Framework, I have to refresh the EDMX file, [which MS explains here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716697(v=vs.100).aspx), and this works most of the time.  I'm just curious if there is a way to automate this by passing in a server and telling a program/function to refresh all objects, or is the only opttion to refresh an EDMX manually through the GUI.

Thanks!

Comment: I have not seen a way to automate this process.  Possible duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935317/how-can-i-automatically-update-entity-framework-function-imports

Comment: https://github.com/jradxl/Generate-Database-Edmx-Automation may be a tool here.  I would recommend doing it manually, still